# General instances of val or var using scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, dsl

**How can I use a macro to generate a val?**

For example, I want this code to be generated :

```
val test = new Test("arg1")
```

.. using a "simpler" syntax ..

```
test := "arg1"
```

Are macros the answer?  If not, an internal DSL/implicit conversions?  I want to avoid building an external DSL.

What if multiple arguments are needed?

Comment: Is it true that avoiding "`val`" is an important part of what you want to achieve? If so, I doubt you can do it with internal DSL and/or macros as what you get is not a valid Scala source code anyway (unless you are going to put all of your code inside a plain `String` and parse it inside your macros). AFAIU both internal DSL and Macros require a valid Scala source code to start with.

Comment: use a different language which offers such "simpler" syntax.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Not helpful, sorry.

Comment: @SergGr Any idea how sbt implements their configuration files?

Comment: @edc, some details on sbt are too big for a comment so I put it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @SergGr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sbt is the source of your inspiration, then they do non-trivial tricks. If you look at [ConsoleProject.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/ConsoleProject.scala), you can see that they run Scala compiler themselves and they pass `initCommands` which is build using `imports` which in turn includes [`BuildUtil.getImports`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/BuildUtil.scala#L78-L85) which uses

```
def baseImports: Seq[String] =
   "import _root_.scala.xml.{TopScope=>$scope}" :: "import _root_.sbt._" :: "import _root_.sbt.Keys._" :: Nil
```

And the imported [Keys.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala) define all the setting keys that you can assign with `:=`. And then they use a bunch of macros defined at [TaskMacro.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/main-settings/src/main/scala/sbt/std/TaskMacro.scala) to implement `:=`.

So I would say that sbt uses an external DSL with some clever tricks to use existing Scala infrastructure to compile it without rolling out a full-blown custom compiler.